# Sparkfun SC16IS750 multiple read

Tags: embedded, i2c

I am struggling to get multiple read for the RHR register working on my  SC16IS750 breakout board. I am using the board with I2C standard frequency and
normal single reads and write are working.
The chip has a FiFo which can hold up to 64 characters. The Fig 24 in the Chip Manual (http://www.nxp.com/documents/data_sheet/SC16IS740_750_760.pdf) shows how it should work.
However when initiating such a multiple read only the first character is correctly transfered. All other characters are "0". If eg the FiFO held 16 characters before the transfer it will be empty afterwards.
Here what I do when receiving a FiFO Interrupt from the Chip:
 - Read interrupt status register IIR
 - Read Line Status register
 - Read RX Level register RXLVL - ie number of Charcaters in Fifo
 - Read Multiple data:
 I2C start, slave address+write, register address, repeated start, slave address+read, read charcter, ACK...read last character, NACK

I'll send a test pattern to the chip with 16 characters, only the first character is correct the rest are "0". RXLVL shows 16 before read.
Does anybody know what needs to be setup/considered for this operation with the NXP chip?

Comment: Hardware questions are off-topic here. Unless your problem is specifically about how to implement/trouble-shoot the source code for this, the question should be posted at https://electronics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: This is not a hardware question. It is releated on how multiple reads should be implemented in the driver. Sorry to be unspecific here

Comment: It is still a question about how this specific IC behaves. At any rate, these kind of questions will get a better reception on the electronics site.

Comment: I will raise the question on the eletronics site. Thanks!